# Jenkins CI: 'NumberFormatException: in report generation

Tags: jenkins

We have a Jenkins installed and some projects which are tested by JUnit. This works fine and it writes an JUnit results XML file. Then we have a 'Publish JUnit test result report' post-build step. But for the last two days it produces this error:

```
09:03:07 Recording test results
09:03:07 ERROR: Step ?Publish JUnit test result report? aborted due to exception: 
09:03:07 java.io.IOException: remote file operation failed: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/raas_flow_test at hudson.remoting.Channel@27420623:slave1: java.io.IOException: Failed to read /var/jenkins_home/workspace/raas_flow_test/repository/com.sap.brms.repository.service.odata.flow.test/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.sap.brms.repository.service.odata.flow.test.neo.suite.NeoFlowTestSuite.xml
09:03:07    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:986)
09:03:07    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:968)
09:03:07    at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitParser.parseResult(JUnitParser.java:103)
09:03:07    at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver.parse(JUnitResultArchiver.java:127)
09:03:07    at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver.perform(JUnitResultArchiver.java:148)
09:03:07    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:78)
09:03:07    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
09:03:07    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:782)
09:03:07    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:723)
09:03:07    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:185)
09:03:07    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:668)
09:03:07    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1763)
09:03:07    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
09:03:07    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
09:03:07    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
09:03:07 Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to read /var/jenkins_home/workspace/raas_flow_test/repository/com.sap.brms.repository.service.odata.flow.test/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.sap.brms.repository.service.odata.flow.test.neo.suite.NeoFlowTestSuite.xml
09:03:07    at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(TestResult.java:306)
09:03:07    at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parsePossiblyEmpty(TestResult.java:244)
09:03:07    at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(TestResult.java:175)
09:03:07    at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(TestResult.java:154)
09:03:07    at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.<init>(TestResult.java:126)
09:03:07    at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitParser$ParseResultCallable.invoke(JUnitParser.java:132)
09:03:07    at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitParser$ParseResultCallable.invoke(JUnitParser.java:107)
09:03:07    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2719)
09:03:07    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:120)
09:03:07    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
09:03:07    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:332)
09:03:07    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
09:03:07    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
09:03:07    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
09:03:07    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
09:03:07    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
09:03:07    at ......remote call to slave1(Native Method)
09:03:07    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1416)
09:03:07    at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:220)
09:03:07    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:781)
09:03:07    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:979)
09:03:07    ... 14 more
09:03:07 Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1,154.768"
09:03:07    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
09:03:07    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
09:03:07    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:451)
09:03:07    at hudson.tasks.junit.SuiteResult.<init>(SuiteResult.java:170)
09:03:07    at hudson.tasks.junit.SuiteResult.parseSuite(SuiteResult.java:144)
09:03:07    at hudson.tasks.junit.SuiteResult.parse(SuiteResult.java:129)
09:03:07    at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(TestResult.java:301)
09:03:07    at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parsePossiblyEmpty(TestResult.java:244)
09:03:07    at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(TestResult.java:175)
09:03:07    at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(TestResult.java:154)
09:03:07    at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.<init>(TestResult.java:126)
09:03:07    at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitParser$ParseResultCallable.invoke(JUnitParser.java:132)
09:03:07    at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitParser$ParseResultCallable.invoke(JUnitParser.java:107)
09:03:07    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2719)
09:03:07    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:120)
09:03:07    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
09:03:07    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:332)
09:03:07    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
09:03:07    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
09:03:07    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
09:03:07    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
09:03:07    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
09:03:07 Finished: FAILURE
```

Why has it started producing this error message?

Comment: The code would be useful, though I think the message `Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1,154.768"`is pretty straightforward